# How to access a Textbox in Form3 from Form1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In (Form1) i have a setting button, when i click on it a new form ( Form2 ) is shown, using these lines of code :

```
private void b7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 frm = new Form3();
    frm.Show();

}
```

In form3, i have 6 text boxes, and two button, Save and Cancel.

[image]

What i'm trying to do is to provide this form to the user so he types the neccessary data into the form, then he click the Save Settings button. In Form1, i want to access to these text boxes to get their current values ( when user clicked save settings ). I tried to add a Form4 and named it ( MiddleForm), i added 6 text boxes to it, and in Form3 (The form in the image above) i wrote these line :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MiddleForm mf = new MiddleForm();
    mf.textBox1.Text = keywrd1.Text;
    mf.textBox2.Text = keywrd2.Text;
    mf.textBox3.Text = keywrd3.Text;
    mf.textBox4.Text = keywrd4.Text;
    mf.textBox5.Text = keywrd5.Text;

    mf.textBox1.Text = thelink.Text;

    Close();


}
```

then i tried to access the values passed to the MiddleForm from Form1 (The form where i need to use the textboxes values), in Form1, i wrote these lines (for debug purposes only)

```
MiddleForm mf = new MiddleForm();

MessageBox.Show(mf.textBox1.Text); // to see whether there is something
```

Unfortunately, it seems that nothing is passed to mf.TextBox1

[image]

How can i call the current values (Saved using save settings button) of Form3  From Form1 in order to use them in the rest of code.

Any help please on getting this to work ?

Comment: Wow ... please name the UI elements something meaningful.  My head is spinning trying to follow all the "form3"s, "button18_click"s, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a textbox value from Form1 to Form2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384961/how-to-copy-a-textbox-value-from-form1-to-form2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make public properties in `Form3` like this

```
public string[] Keys
{
    get
    {
        return new string[] { tbKey1.Text, tbKey2.Text, tbKey3.Text,
                              tbKey4.Text, tbKey5.Text};
    }
}

public string Link { get { return tbLink.Text; } }
```

From `Form1` you can access these properties like this

```
Form3 frm = new Form3();
if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    string[] keys = frm.Keys; 
    string link = frm.Link; 
}
```

Note: It is important that you use `ShowDialog` and not `Show`, since `Show` does not wait for the other form to close. Also, when "Save settings" is clicked in `Form3`, set the dialog result

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
Close();
```

so that you can check it in `Form1` as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

Make 6 public properties in your Form3 like that:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public string Value1
    {
        get { return this.keywrd1.Text; }
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get { return this.keywrd2.Text; }
    }

    ...
}
```

After your Form3 is closed (but before disposed) you can access text values via properties. As pointed in another answer, use ShowDialog instead of Show and close Form3 inside it's own code.

```
private void b7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 frm = new Form3();
    frm.ShowDialog();
    string value1 = frm.Value1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form3;
String myText = form.txtBoxName.Text;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make a public field that provides the values you want to get out of the form.  If you go to the source of Form1, you should add in something like this:

```
public string TextValue1 {
    get {return TextBox1.Text;}
}
```

Now, you can use the Form1.TextBox1 to retrieve a string value from your Textbox.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) it will create your `Form` as a Model Dialog box, you can then check the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) to know wether the data was saved or the `Form` was canceled.

i.e.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 frm = new Form3();
    if (frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        savedSettings = frm.getTextBoxValues();
    }
}
```

**Form3**

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    string[] textValues = new string[6];

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string[] getTextBoxValues()
    {
        return textValues;
    }

    private void saveSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        textValues[0] = textBox1.Text;
        textValues[1] = textBox2.Text;
        textValues[2] = textBox3.Text;
        textValues[3] = textBox4.Text;
        textValues[4] = textBox5.Text;
        textValues[5] = textBox6.Text;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cancelSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```