# How to access form1.webbrowser from form3?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I made a web browser in C# Windows forms, and I made form 3 to be the history, form 3 contains listbox and a button called go!

I want button_click to navigate the webbrowser1 (located in form1) to `listbox1.selecteditem.tostring()`.

In form1 constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    x = new Form3();
    x.Show();
    x.Visible = false;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and in the button that open the form 3

```
{
    x.Visible = true;
}
```

in form 3 button that says go :

```
{
    // namespace.form1.webbrowser1.navigate(listbox1.selecteditem.tostring()); // 
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

the error in the comment line , what is the solution to access the webbrowser from form 3 !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a Textbox in Form3 from Form1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158051/how-to-access-a-textbox-in-form3-from-form1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `Form1` to `Form3` constructor as parameter:

```
class Form3
{
    Form1 _parent;
    public Form3(Form1 parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        _parent.webbrowser1.navigate(listbox1.selecteditem.tostring());
        this.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

also, make `webbrowser1` `public` or better make a public method in `Form1`:

```
class Form1
{  
    public void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        webbrowser1.navigate(uri);
    }
}
```

and call it from `Form3`:

```
    public void Method()
    {
        _parent.Navigate(listbox1.selecteditem.tostring());
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Backs i made all of this it's perfect but there is one small error in form1 constructor when i make :
public Form1()

{
    
    x = new Form3(here is the error what should i pass here);
    x.Show();
    x.Visible = false;
    InitializeComponent();

}

Comment: @MohammedMoataz `x = new Form3(this);` - instance of `Form1` class

Comment: no it's working i forgot to initialize components in form 3 constructor :D

Comment: Thank you very much , hope to u awesome day :D <3